# Multiple root error in Layout- how to fix it?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Hello evreyone,

I get this error from my Layout XML: `Multiple root error`. So I tried a lot to fix it yet could not find any solution, please help me about it:

this is my code from file layout xml:
   [image]

thanks a lot :)

Comment: add your layout code as text not as image

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one element in your XML that doesn't have a parent. By sparse information you gave us, you have at least two root elements: `<RelativeLayout>` and `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >`.

To fix this error you just need to move `</RelativeLayout>` (closing tag) after DrawerLayout, that is to the end of the document. Or, probably better, move `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >` to the beginning, enclosing other layouts.

However even if you do fix error you're getting this is not good implementation. You should read more about DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting Multiple root error in Layout because of
**in Android every xml file there must be only one root layout**

so try to add single parent  to your layout

**sample code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <!-- add here your other controlls or layouts-->


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_home_class"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_class"
            app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```